# EKS provisions nodes more than maxnodes using Karpenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, provisioning, amazon-eks

Currently I am using EKS with karpenter and I provision EKS cluster with values
minNodes: 1
maxNodes: 2
DesiredNodes: 1

Then I setup the karpenter using [this link](https://karpenter.sh/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-karpenter/). After Setting it up as referred by the docs of karpenter that I have linked above I tested the node provisioning by creating a deployment which uses a **pause image**. Then I scaled the replicas of the deployment upto 5. Now Instead of provisioning the nodes upto the **maxNodes** values it provisioned 5 nodes.

ManagedNodesGroups config

```
amiFamily: AmazonLinux2
    instanceType: m5a.large
    iam:
      withAddonPolicies:
        autoScaler: true
        cloudWatch: true
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 2
    desiredCapacity: 1
    volumeSize: 25
    volumeType: gp3
```

Note: I have used below limits in karpenter NodePool

```
 limits:
    cpu: 1000
    memory: 1000Gi
```